# I need to remove some characters from a SQL field without altering database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, replace, html-table

I am using a database that was already created and I can access, but do not have the permission to alter the database at all.

I am using the query

```
select last_count, query, job_id from twitterinblack46.job where job_id in ('.$job_id_all.') order by last_count desc;
```

to call three columns (`last_count`, `query`, and `job_id`) and display them in a table.

This query works as I want it to, but the only issue is the `query` column displays data with either a "%23","%40","%20", or "q=" in front of the desired data.

I need to figure out how to get rid of these strings before displaying the table.

Here is the while statement used to generate the table:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo"<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["job_id"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["last_count"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['query'] . "</td>";
    echo "<tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

I have created this query:

```
select replace(replace(replace(REPLACE(query,'%23', ''),'%40',''),'q=',''),'%20','') from job;
```

to get rid of these characters and it works perfectly as I need it, but how can I incorporate this query into my other `$result` before creating the table?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. What language are you using ? If php consider urldecode() tips

Comment: I am using php to access a SQL database.

Comment: So why don't you use urldecode like stuff to treat your data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the offending strings when printing the table:

```
echo "<td>" . str_replace(array('%23', '%40', '%20"', 'q='), '', $row['query']) . "</td>";
```

(If you want to limit removal to only characters at the beginning of the string you can look at [preg_replace](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php))

Comment: You can also specify an extra `count` equal to 1 argument for `str_replace` if you only want to remove the first characters in the string.

Comment: Hey one more thing, can I use prey_replace to get rid of 0's in front of numbers in the last_count column as well or will it not work with int's?

Answer (score 1):

```
$lst_search = array("%23", "%40", "%20", "q=");
$query = str_replace($lst_search, "", $row["query"]);
```

Then use `$query` in place of `$row["query"]` when creating the table.

Comment: This isn't working because I ask for user input to enter in as many job ID's as they want separated by commas and then I create an array of these ID's to add to the query.

Comment: @Pstivala7  I don't understand.  You said you only had a problem wit the `query` column.  Just add the above code before your while statement and use $query inside your code instead of $row["query"]..